# error: undefined reference to cv::imwrite, what is a problem here?

Tags: cmake

I am working with android native and use `CMake`. I need to use a `cv::imwrite` method from `OpenCV`, but when I use it in my code I get such an error:

```
error: undefined reference to cv::imwrite
```

It seems that I added everything right in `CMakeList.txt`

```
...
set(pathToOpenCv $ENV{OPEN_CV_PATH})
include_directories(${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

target_link_libraries(decoder_engine_lib
        mediandk
        oboe::oboe
        android
        lib_opencv
        ${log-lib}
)
...
```

What am I missing here? Why I get this error in spite file is exist and `#include` added?